# POST request delete + symball

Tags: android, post, request, rest-client

I have this code

```
httpUriRequest = new HttpPost(address.toString());
((HttpPost)httpUriRequest).setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(restParams.postData()));
httpUriRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
```

When I'm sending `"asd+asd"` server gets `"asdasd"` or `"asd asd"`. Also I try to send this string by rest-client to server and it works well.

So what's the problem? Can anyone suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Its replacing "+" with space because in the HTML URL Encoding the "+" symbol is considered as the space and its always replaced with the space.

Basically you need to make sure the variables you are passing are encoded (the '%' character is a special character in URL encoding).

Any special characters - %,?,&, etc... need to be encoded. They are encoded with '%' and their hex number. So '%' should become '%25', '&' becomes '%26', etc.

Check out: [escape, or encodeURI / encodeURIComponent for why you should avoid using escape.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

One solution is that you make your request url into the Post method and post your request in the form of NameValuePair.

Check out the [URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)